# Import .obj from SH3D “Sweet Home 3D”

Tags: objects, import

I have exported my forniture from SH3D to .obj and now i have the .jpg texture file, .obl and .mtl files. In Blender import the file .obj, but after a quick loading Blender return to the home without loading anything and without giving me any message.

Comment: Welcome to Blender.Se. Does the vert, faces edges statististics of the scenes are all set to zero? Is the outliner empty?

Comment: Grazie Carlo, purtroppo sono alle prime armi con Blender, per cui non so dove controllare i dati che mi hai indicato.

Il file .obj l'ho caricato correttamente su MeshLab e poi esportato in ltri molti formati, ma Blender si comporta sempre allo stesso modo

Comment: Remember that the official language of the site is english, so it would be better to write everything that way so anyone can help. If you take a screenshot of the whole screeen with blender right after importing the obj and post it here we can see ourself (something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkyVx.png)

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/

Comment: [How do I apply textures to imported .obj?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/97190/2217), [How do I add a texture when Importing from OBJ scan?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/65918/2217), and [Importing OBJ with MTL and Image not working properly](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/24020/2217)